# sql how i get username from seesion id?

Tags: php, mysql

Now i have doing a chatroom but now all the message with username is getting from my seesion username. you log in what name all the username will same with you. how do i getting username from my user database with session_user id?

my table is

- **user** - have id,username
- **chatroom** have id,name
- **chatroom_chat** have chatroom_id whihc is relationship with chatroom,chat_id relationship with chat
- **chat** have id,user_id,chat.date

how do i get the user_id from chat and get the username from user table?

here is my code with php and sql

```
    $chatroomID=$_GET['chatroomID'];
$userID = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM chatroom_chat";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $chat = $row['chat_id'];
    $getChatData = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id = '$chat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,40
        ) sub
        ORDER BY id ASC ") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($getChatData)) {
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            $color = ($row3['user_id'] == $userID) ? '#FFFFFF' : '#66FFFF';
            $position = ($row3['user_id'] == $userID ) ? 'right' : 'left';
            $border = ($row3['user_id'] == $userID) ? ' 1px solid black ' : ' none ';

            echo "<div class='msg-dateandtime' style='text-align:$position; float:$position;'> <div class='left-username' style='color:blue;'>" .$username."</div>"
                    . "<div class='space'></div>"
                    . "<div class='right-date'>  ". $row3['date'] ." </div></div>"
                    . "<div class='wrap-message' style='background-color:$color; border:$border; float:$position;'>"
                    . "<p style 'text-align=$position; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:left;'> ".$row3['chat']."</p></div>";
        }

}
```

Comment: What would the *plain SQL* look like? The PHP is largely irrelevant, unless this question is about finding a bug in code..

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped

Answer (score 1):

From your post, I am assuming this is your only question: **"how do i getting username from my user database with session_user id?"**

You showed us that your **user** table content is as follows:

```
      user
   __________________
  |  id  |  username |
  |------|-----------|
  |   1  |    jack   |
  |   2  |    sam    |
  |   3  |    ana    |
```

So if the `session_user` in your question is the equivalent id to the id in the **user** table, you could use the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM username WHERE id = {$_SESSION['session_user']}";
```

The previous code is assuming that `session_user` is the key value in your `$_SESSION` super global. However, if `session_user` is an actual **php** variable in your code (`$session_user`), then just replace `$_SESSION['session_user']` with `$session_user` in the previous sql statement.

Comment: i was using multiple query to get my username ~ but anyways still thank you fro your answer